# Checking other checkboxes when clicking on a checkbox and saving them to MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database, checkbox

I'm working with MySQL and when you click on the checkboxes, they save their data/value (tinyint(1)) to the database table, so it'll be shown as checkbox either checked or not checked.

Simply said now I want to for examples:

- **When clicking on Grade 3 that also Grade 2, Grade 1 and Obtained will be checked and saved.**
- **When clicking on Grade 2, only Grade 2 and Grade 1 will be checked**
- **This also means that if for example all are checked** (Obtained, Grade 1, Grade 2 and Grade 3) **and you would uncheck Grade 2, that both Grade 3 and Grade 4 will unchecked too**

I tried some scripts before but if I clicked for example Grade 3, both Grade 1 and Grade 2 would be checked but when I refreshed the page only gradetwo would have changed. So that it doesn't matter if I close the browser, change the browser, the checkboxes are still checked the way I left them. I sadly don't know much about coding to fix this.

To give a little more details: I'm trying to make something like a Equipment Tracker? for a game. There are 100+ weapons, armors etc inside that game and I put all of them inside my MySQL database, all of them have a unique ID, the name of the equipment and 4 checkboxes which will indicate if I have obtained this and then upgraded them up to maximum Grade 3.

For example weapons look like this in the table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDyCn.jpg

Name - [1]Obtained - [2]Grade 1 - [3]Grade 2 - [4]Grade 3

Weapon 01 - [1] - [2] - [3] - [4]
~
Weapon 04 - [X] - [X] - [X] - [X]
~
Weapon 07 - [X] - [X] - [3] - [4]

If I were to sell a Grade 3 Weapon (Weapon 04 for example), it means I will lose it and would have to obtain it again, so by clicking op [1], it'll also remove [2][3][4].

Hopefully this makes sense and that someone can help me with this.

Down below are some pieces of the code I'm using currently to hopefully give you some idea.

**Part of Index.php**

```
echo "<div id=msg_display></div>";

$q="
SELECT id,name
     , if( obtained=true,'checked','') as obtained
     , if( gradeone=true,'checked','') as gradeone
     , if( gradetwo=true,'checked','') as gradetwo
     , if( gradethree=true,'checked','') as gradethree
  FROM weapons
";


echo "<table class='table table-striped'> ";
$th="<tr class='info'> <th>Name</th><th>obtained</th><th>gradeone</th><th>gradetwo</th><th>gradethree</th></tr>";
echo $th; 
$i=1;
if ($result_set = mysqli_query($connection,$q)) {
while($row = $result_set->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
echo "<tr><td>$row[name]</td>
<input type=checkbox data-column_name='obtained' data-id='$row[id]' $row[obtained]>
<input type=checkbox data-column_name='gradeone' data-id='$row[id]' $row[gradeone]>
<input type=checkbox data-column_name='gradetwo' data-id='$row[id]' $row[gradetwo]>
<input type=checkbox data-column_name='gradethree' data-id='$row[id]' $row[gradethree]>
</tr>";

";
$i=$i+1;
if(fmod($i,10)==0){//echo $th;
}
}
 $result_set->close();
}
```

**Script inside Index.php**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
////////////////////    
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
var column_name=$(32).data('column_name');
var id=$(this).data('id');
$.post( "data-check.php", {"column_name":$(this).data('column_name'),"id":$(this).data('id')},function(return_data,status){
$("#msg_display").html(return_data);
$("#msg_display").show();
setTimeout(function() { $("#msg_display").fadeOut('slow'); }, 5000);
});
});
//////////////////////////
});
</script>
```

**data-check.php**

```
<?php
$column_name=$_POST['column_name'];
$id=$_POST['id'];
if(!ctype_alpha($column_name)){
echo " Data error ";
exit;
}
include "config-mysqli.php"; // database connection details stored here
$q=" 
UPDATE weapons 
   SET $column_name = !$column_name 
 WHERE id=?
 ";
$stmt = $connection->prepare($q);
if($stmt){
$stmt->bind_param('i',  $id);
$stmt->execute();   
$msg="Data Updated for : $column_name ";    
}else {
$msg="No Data Updated for : $column_name ";     
}
echo "$msg";
?>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to do that by JavaScript in the Client? You don't need to connect to a database for this job

Comment: @Strawberry Ah my bad, I took this code from something else amd forgot to take that out.

Comment: @ChristophSchreiber I'm sorry I honestly don't know what you mean, a reason I use a database is that I don't want to lose the checkbox choices I made so that I could see it/continue on other browsers for example.

Comment: @Tadakun I mean: (un)checking other checkboxes by using JavaScript locally in the browser. And only updating the status by AJAX.

Comment: There's no point storing ('saving') anything other than the max level per game. Can beginner ever be unchecked?

Comment: @Strawberry It can and needs to be able to get unchecked, I changed my post to hopefully explain it better and as to why I (like to) store all of it. My apologies for the possible confusion. I might even be making this the wrong or making it too hard for myself.

Comment: Could you please add images to the question, it is hard to understand what you are trying to tell us.

Comment: You're confusing data display with data storage and retrieval. Please don't add images.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following which, if nothing else, will at least demonstrate that I am terrible at writing code...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS inventory;

CREATE TABLE inventory
(user_id INT NOT NULL
,weapon_id INT NOT NULL
,level_code TINYINT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(user_id,weapon_id)
);

INSERT INTO inventory VALUES (1,101,1),(1,102,2),(1,103,3);
INSERT INTO inventory VALUES (2,104,3);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS weapons;

CREATE TABLE weapons
(weapon_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,weapon_name VARCHAR(12) UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO weapons VALUES
(101,'nudger'),
(102,'poker'),
(103,'blaster'),
(104,'pulverizer');
```

By inspection, we can see that user 1 owns all weapons except the pulverizer.

```
<?php

require('path/to/pdo/connection/statme.nts');

$query = "
SELECT w.weapon_id
     , w.weapon_name
     , COALESCE(i.level_code,0) level
  FROM weapons w
  LEFT
  JOIN inventory i
    ON i.weapon_id = w.weapon_id
   AND i.user_id = 1
 ORDER
    BY weapon_id;
";
$stmt  = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$data  = $stmt->fetchAll();

?>

<table>
   <tr>
    <th>weapon name</th>
    <th>Grade I</th>
    <th>Grade II</th>
    <th>Grade III</th>
    <th>Grade IV</th>
   </tr>

<?php

$flag1 =0;
$flag2 =0;
$flag3 =0;
$flag4 =0;

foreach( $data as $v ) {
if($v['level']>=1) {$flag1=1;} else {$flag1=0;}
if($v['level']>=2) {$flag2=1;} else {$flag2=0;}
if($v['level']>=3) {$flag3=1;} else {$flag3=0;}
if($v['level']>=4) {$flag4=1;} else {$flag4=0;}

  echo "<tr>
         <td>".$v['weapon_name']."</td>
         <td>$flag1</td>
         <td>$flag2</td>
         <td>$flag3</td>
         <td>$flag4</td>
        <tr>";
}
?>

</table>
```

Outputs:

```
weapon name Grade I Grade II Grade III Grade IV
nudger         1       0        0         0
poker          1       1        0         0
blaster        1       1        1         0
pulverizer     0       0        0         0
```

Comment: Atleast you know how to write code, whereas I know how to copy and paste. Speaking of which I'm confused as to where I should put that code and how to try and get it work haha, like shall I just paste everything in the index.php for example or somewhere else

Comment: It's up to you. I would just make a separate page. Mine happens to be called 'checkbox_fun.php' even though I didn't actually make any checkboxes.